# Practical Examples - Where MongoDB / Cassandra can NOT be used

Tags: mongodb, cassandra

I am assessing a situation which one to use Mongo DB Vs Cassandra. There are many articles those focuses on differences etc in general.

However, what they are missing is a real, practical example - say Cassandra performs well for Product Catalogues while mongo cant for the same scenarios etc ..

Please shed your experiences why you choose mongoDB over cassandra OR cassandra over mongodb

Comment: I think there are not so many situations where you have to use MongoDB or Cassandra. Usually it is a trade-off and either database has benefits and disadvantages. For sure one practical situation is: Your application does not support connection to MongoDB or Cassandra. For example [syslog-ng](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.18/administration-guide/29#TOPIC-1043990) can send log messages to MongoDB but not to Cassandra (at least not natively), so Cassandra would be no option.

Answer (score -1):

> However, what they are missing is a real, practical example - say Cassandra performs well for Product Catalogues while mongo cant for the same scenarios etc ..

Usually when a system is designed, the requirements or system design can be adjusted to compensate for limitations of various components used.

For example, MongoDB has a hard limit of 16 mb on the size of an individual document. But it also provides GridFS to store arbitrarily large documents, except those are no longer queryable with MQL. And the application can potentially split the data to be in smaller documents.

Therefore, saying something like "MongoDB does not support documents over 16 mb" is not, by itself, completely accurate or useful.

System designers look at the use cases they must support in their system and at the capabilities of the components (in this case the database) to roughly align the two, then figure out any difficulties that must be addressed and address those.

Comment: sounds very generic, please share "specific" practical challenges / advantages one over other for OP. Thanks

Comment: I provided one.